# Custom section in XML config file in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a question, a problem with configuration.

I am running an application under .net core 2.0 with custom configuration file that looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="mailingListSection" type="ConfigurationTool.AppServer.PersistenceLayer.Entities.MailingList, ConfigurationTool.AppServer.PersistenceLayer.Entities" />
  </configSections>

  <mailingListSection>
    <mails>
      <mail value="test1@test.com" />
     <mail value="test2@test.com" />
   </mails>
 </mailingListSection>

 <appSettings>
   <add key="Path" value="Value"/>
 </appSettings>
```

Now as you see I have a custom section, and i want to get that from config so i have created configure element collection:

```
namespace ConfigurationTool.AppServer.PersistenceLayer.Entities
{
    public class MailingList : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("mails")]
        public MailElementCollection Mails
        {
            get => (MailElementCollection)base["mails"];
            set => base["mails"] = value;
        }
    }
    public class MailElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("value", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
        public string Value => (string)base["value"];
    }

    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(MailElement))]
    public class MailElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        internal const string PropertyName = "mail";

        public override ConfigurationElementCollectionType CollectionType => ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMapAlternate;

        protected override string ElementName => PropertyName;

        protected override bool IsElementName(string elementName)
        {
            return elementName.Equals(PropertyName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }

        public override bool IsReadOnly()
        {
            return false;
        }

        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new MailElement();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((MailElement)element).Value;
        }

        public new MailElement this[string value] => (MailElement)BaseGet(value);
    }
}
```

And try to call it:

```
var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = "persistenceLayer.config" };
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

var mailingList = config.GetSection("mailingListSection");
```

But I am getting

> Blockquote
>   An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for mailingListSection: 
>   Could not load file or assembly 
>   'ConfigurationTool.AppServer.PersistenceLayer.Entities, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I have check my main app catalog configuration file is there also the ConfigurationTool.AppServer.PersistenceLayer.dll is there, and I've run of ideas, what could be wrong?

Also information is that main application is referring to that one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `ConfigurationTool.AppServer.PersistenceLayer.Entities` is set as a reference in your project. Then click the reference in the references list and in the properties window set Copy Local to true.